# Python move file prom directory

Tags: python, rutas

Quiero mover unos archivos de un directorio a otro.

Si hago esto sí funciona bien:

```
folder = "/mnt/c/Users/TEAMA-TL5/Documents/Datos_procesados_tanks_270422/exportedData_IP1/"

directory = "Test1.3.4/"
path = os.path.join(folder, directory)
os.mkdir(path)

shutil.move("/mnt/c/Users/TEAMA-TL5/Documents/Datos_procesados_tanks_270422/exportedData_IP1/Test1.3.4__26042022_172940_VDR_1002_20210127_073935_CH0.txt", "/mnt/c/Users/TEAMA-TL5/Documents/Datos_procesados_tanks_270422/exportedData_IP1/Test1.3.4/Test1.3.4__26042022_172940_VDR_1002_20210127_073935_CH0.txt")
```

Pero con ello sólo movería un archivo, lo que me gustaría hacer es mover todos los archivos que comienzan de una manera a su mismo directorio, al hacer esto no funciona bien:

```
folder = "/mnt/c/Users/TEAMA-TL5/Documents/Datos_procesados_tanks_270422/exportedData_IP1/"

directory = "Test1.3.4/"
path = os.path.join(folder, directory)
os.mkdir(path)

try:
  for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.startswith("Test1.3.4"):
      shutil.move(folder+filename, folder+directory+filename)
except:
  print("exception")
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no funciona bien"?

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizas `shutil.copytree` para copiar el directório completo?

Comment: Buenas! El comando en linux sería: `mv Test1.3.4* **(DIR DONDE QUIERAS MOVERLOS)**` . Adaptarlo a python y listos

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que `os.listdir()` trae todo, incluyendo subdirectorios, creo que el problema está en que el script está tratando de mover el directorio destino dentro de si mismo, provocando un error dentro del ciclo `for`, que, aunque está dentro de un bloque `try`, no está cubierto. Eso quiere decir que el bloque `try/except` también está mal implementado.

[*] Será algo "basado en opiniones", pero no debes meter grandes bloques de código, funciones o bucles dentro de bloques `try/except` (`catch`) ya que si los mismos entran en error, se cierran sin comunicar al desarrollador que ocurrió, provocando comportamiento impredecible (bugs) en el programa. Ningún error debe ser pasado por alto.

El código debería quedar:

```
folder = "/mnt/c/Users/TEAMA-TL5/Documents/Datos_procesados_tanks_270422/exportedData_IP1/"

directory = "Test1.3.4/"
path = os.path.join(folder, directory)
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True) # Python 3.2+ || Crear directorio si no existe

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    src = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    if filename.startswith("Test1.3.4") and os.path.isfile(src):
        # Si comienza por Test1.3.4 y es un archivo (no directorio)
        dst = os.path.join(folder, directory, filename)
        try:
            shutil.move(src, dst)
        except:
            print("exception")
```

Comment: Concuerdo con tu opinión de que el try debe tener la menor cantidad de código posible dentro.